# From Python to C#. Starting from zero?

Tags: c#, python, arrays, random

I'm almost finished with MIT OpenCourseWare about Computer Science and I have a big problem. Everything there was in Python and now I have to use C# because of my studies but I'm lost, I'm totally lost, I have no idea what I'm doing, how this and that works. I can't understand almost no concept in C#. I'm reading guides, tutorials. I read many topics/question here also. Any suggestions? I just tried to write something on my own like a script on my friends game but I'm stuck. I can't even choose a random array from two dimensional array and then iterate over that chosen array.

```
class MainClass
    {
        static double[]result = { 120, 160, 200 };
        static double[,]steeds = {
            {150,0,255} , //black steed
            {255,150,0} , //maroon steed
            {0,255,150}   //white steed
        };
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            double[]random_steed = steeds[ ////here i cant even type a char "r" it gives me "Random" automatically
        }
```

I would like to choose a random array from that 2-dimensional one and then iterate over it. Please help me.

Comment: If you are forced to use .NET, you can use IronPython.

Comment: Rob Mile's Yellow Book is the best introduction out there for C#. It assumes no background and it is very clear.

Comment: Don't panic: if you understood Python, you can learn C#. You'll have to learn new syntaxes and libraries (including data structures and ways of doing things), but you can learn it.

Comment: And no, you're not starting from zero. Programming is more about thinking how to work through a problem than it is syntax.

Comment: Sarge Borsch - no im not forced to.
Jack_of_All_Trades - thanks a lot im already reading it:))
Tim S. - ill do my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double[,]` is a [multi-dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). While these have their uses, they can be difficult to use, and are not commonly used. You might want to use a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) like `double[][]`. You can use it like this:

```
static double[]result = { 120, 160, 200 };
static double[][]steeds = {
    new double[] {150,0,255} , //black steed
    new double[] {255,150,0} , //maroon steed
    new double[] {0,255,150}   //white steed
};
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    double[] random_steed = steeds[r.Next(steeds.Length)];
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", random_steed)); // might print 255,150,0
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great. I hope i will be able to understand all the things in code soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track. I would try something like this.

```
int r1 = r.Next(0, 2);
int r2 = r.Next(0, 2);
double random_steed = steeds[r1, r2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer:)